# Is the Principal Logarithm Function Entire and Can Its Value Ever Be Less Than 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, entire-functions

Define the Principal Logarithm as Follows:

Log(*z*) = ln|z| + *i*Arg(*z*)

Where z is not equal to 0, z = r$e^{iθ}$, and θ = arg(z) and θ lies on (-π, π].

Is this function entire? And if so, can its value ever be less than 1?

Comment: No, it is not entire.  For a start it isn't defined at $z=0$.  Furthermore, it is not continuous on the negative real axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function is not continuous and therefore it is not entire. And $\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac12\right)<0$.